# Refreshing a web-page hangs after few times

Tags: ethernet, web-server

I'm using a Nucleo F429ZI board and I wrote a sketch that enables a simple web-server:

```
#include <LwIP.h>
#include <STM32Ethernet.h>

const int WEB_PORT = 80;
EthernetServer server(WEB_PORT);
char buffer[1024];

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    // define variables
    Ethernet.begin(localIP, netmask, dns, gateway);
    server.begin();
}

void loop() 
{
    processServer();
}

void processServer()
{
  String readString; 
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) 
  {
    while (client.connected()) 
    {
      if (client.available()) 
      {
        char c = client.read();
        readString += c; 

        if (c == '\n')
        {
          if (readString.startsWith("GET"))
          {
            readString.remove(0, 4);
            int pos = readString.indexOf(' ');
            String path = readString.substring(0, pos);

            if (path == "/status") pageStatus(client);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    delay(1);
    client.stop();
  }
}

void pageStatus(EthernetClient client)
{
    sectionHeader(client, 2);
    client.println("<html>");
    client.println("<style>table{font-family: verdana, sans-serif;border-collapse: collapse;width: 30%;}");
    client.println("td, th{border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;}tr:nth-child(even)");
    client.println("{background-color: #dddddd;}</style>");
    client.println("<table>");
    client.println("<tr><th>Servo</th><th>Position</th><th>Running</th><th>Initialized</th></tr>");

    for (int i = 0; i < getParamUInt8(P_SERVO_SIZE); i++) 
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "<tr><td>%u</td><td>%d</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", i + 1, (int16_t) _servo[i].current, _servo[i].ended ? "NO" : "YES", _servo[i].initialized ? "YES" : "NO" );
        client.println(buffer);
    }
    client.println("</table>");

    client.println("<br><hr><br>");

    client.println("<table>");
    client.println("<tr><th>Led</th><th>PWM</th><th>Running</th></tr>");

    for (int i = 0; i < getParamUInt8(P_LED_SIZE); i++) 
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "<tr><td>%u</td><td>%d</td><td>%s</td></tr>", i + 1, (int16_t) _led[i].pwm, _led[i].ended ? "NO" : "YES");
        client.println(buffer);
    }
    client.println("</table>");

    client.println("<br><hr><br>");

    client.println("<table>");
    client.println("<tr><th>Stepper</th><th>Position</th><th>Running</th></tr>");

    for (int i = 0; i < getParamUInt8(P_STEPPER_SIZE); i++) 
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "<tr><td>%u</td><td>%d</td><td>%s</td></tr>", i + 1, (int16_t) _stepper[i].stepper.getCurrentPositionInMillimeters(), _stepper[i].stepper.motionComplete() ? "NO" : "YES");
        client.println(buffer);
    }
    client.println("</table>");
    client.println("</html>");
}

void sectionHeader(EthernetClient client, int refresh)
{
    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    if (refresh) client.println("Refresh: 2"); 
    client.println();
    client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
}
```

As you can see in the `sectionHeader()` I want to refresh the page every 2 seconds. It works, but after 3 or 4 refreshes it hangs and I have to reset the whole board.

Of course with an embedded system I would use Ajax... here I thought reloading the page should be enough.

What might cause such a hang?

Comment: I recommend https://www.stm32duino.com

Comment: Welcome to the shockingly bad world of the `String` object. Ditch it as a first priority.

Comment: @Majenko, I used the `String` object only to parse the incoming `GET` request. Do you think it's worth to remove it, about my problem?

Comment: 1. You may want to look at the HTTP conversation with Wireshark. 2. What does your server do when the client requests "GET /favicon.ico"? 3. What if it instead requests "HEAD /favicon.ico"?

Comment: @EdgarBonet, it just doesn't answer. Is this a bad behavior? Should I provide an answer anyway?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have that says `readString += c` has to allocate a whole new string whenever it runs out of space for more characters. All those allocations are filling up memory.

Instead of the String class, use a single C character array, e.g.

char s[128];

that is big enough for whatever you put in it.

If it helps, I wrote a simple arduino web server for my own project, and if you look at the code [here](https://github.com/jspolsky/branchController2/blob/master/lib/WebServer/WebServer.cpp) that may give you ideas for how to implement this.

Comment: Or just set `readString = ""` after processing the request, I guess.